# ¿Como resetear un double a 2 decimales?

Tags: java, double

Como puedo hacer en JAVA para que la variable `pb` con valor `33.3316.67` quede solo como `33.33` , es decir resetear a 2 decimales.

La variable `pb` es `double`.

Comment: Y supongo que nada más te conteste alguien, volverás a eliminar la pregunta. Además te informo que no es la forma adecuada de preguntar, pues no demuestras haberlo intentado. En ésta comunidad no se acostumbra a realizar las tareas de nadie. Pega tu código y tus pruebas para poder obtener una respuesta si es que alguien te desea contestar.

Comment: Es imposible almacenar `33.33` en un `double`. Checa [esta](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) página y de paso la de [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Y hazle caso a el.trasgu

Answer (score 1):

En tu caso, no puedes en un double usar dos `.`

El método que yo uso para redondear a dos decimales es uno que aprendí en internet, la forma sencilla sería usar de la clase `Math` el metodo Round y mediante una división obtener los decimales.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double pb = 33.331667;

        System.out.println(Math.round(pb*100.0)/100.0);
        //Si añades un cero sería obtener 3 decimales, 
        //obviamente hay metodos mejores que este
        //pero para un redondeo a dos decimales es bastante útil.
        System.out.println(Math.round(pb*1000.0)/1000.0);
        


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es **cambiar el valor** de la variable `pb` puedes hacerlo con el método `Math.round()`

```
System.out.println(pb); // 33.331667

pb = Math.round(pb * 100.0) / 100.0;

System.out.println(pb); // 33.33
```

Si lo que necesitas en cambio, es únicamente **imprimir** la variable `pb` mostrando dos decimales, pero manteniendo su valor, puedes utilizar el método `String.format()`

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", pb)); // 33.33

System.out.println(pb); // 33.331667
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta es por medio de Math.round(), de esta manera te redondeará a solo dos decimales la variable, así sería la manera correcta de usarla

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  double pb = 33.3316.67;
  pb = Math.round(dp);
  System.out.println("Valor redondeado a dos decimales: "+ pb);}
```